# Associar imagens à categoria

Tags: php, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um slideshow baseado em categorias. Ou seja, são puxadas do banco de dados as categorias e a elas são associadas as imagens. Todavia, estou tendo 2 problemas. O primeiro se trata das miniaturas das categorias. Uma ou mais miniaturas de categorias aparecem repetidas (2 ou 3 vezes), enquanto outras categorias não são exibidas.

O código é:

```
echo '<h2 class="margin-bototm10" style="text-align:center;">Outras Categorias</h2>';
                $result = $mysql->sql_query("select * from TB_CATEGORIA inner join TB_GALERIA on TB_CATEGORIA.PK_CATEGORIA = TB_GALERIA.CATEGORIA where TB_CATEGORIA.DELETED IS NULL AND TB_CATEGORIA.CODUSUARIO=1 AND TIPO='1'");

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo "<li class='isotope-item col-sm-6 col-md-3' style='list-style-type:none;'>";
                    echo "<div class='item-box'>";
                    echo "<figure>";
                    echo "<a title='".$row['DESCRICAO']."' class='item-hover' href='galerias.php?categoria=".$row['PK_CATEGORIA']."'>";
                    echo " <span class='overlay color2'></span>";
                    echo " <span class='inner'>";
                    echo " <span class='block fa fsize30 fa-picture-o'></span>";
                    echo "<strong>Ver</strong> Galeria                        </span>";
                    echo "</a>";
                    echo "<img class='img-responsive' src='../images/".$row['IMAGEM']."' width='260' height='260' style='max-height: 170px;' />";
                    echo "</figure>";
                    echo "<div class='item-box-desc'>";
                    echo " <small class='item-box-date'> </small>";
                    echo "<small style='display: inline;'>".$row['NOME']."</small>";
                    echo " <div class='row' style='max-width: 250px;'>";
                    echo " <div class='col-md-12'>";
                    echo "   <p class='similar-h4' style='display: inline;'>".$row['NOME']."</p>";
                    echo " </div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo " </div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo "</li>";
```

O outro é o seguinte, no código está para exibir apenas imagens/categorias onde o valor da tabela DELETED for NULL, mudei isso para testar, mas a ideia original é que seja exibido quando a tabela estiver vazia e não nula. Pois por questões de segurança, o que é deletado só recebe a tag * na tabela DELETED e só após alguns dias é realmente excluido. Tentei com DELETED='', mas não funcionou de forma alguma.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1):

Primeira coisa dá um order by na sua query:

```
select * from TB_CATEGORIA 
inner join TB_GALERIA on TB_CATEGORIA.PK_CATEGORIA = TB_GALERIA.CATEGORIA 
where 
   (TB_CATEGORIA.DELETED IS NULL OR TRIM(TB_CATEGORIA.DELETED) <> '')  
   AND TB_CATEGORIA.CODUSUARIO=1 
   AND TIPO='1'
Order by
    TB_CATEGORIA.PK_CATEGORIA
```

O que está acontecendo é que na sua query os resultados vão vir assim:

- Categoria  Figura

  > ```
  > 1        x
  > 1        y
  > 3        qq
  > 4        xx
  > ```

Você terá de fazer um controle quando for imprimir a categoria:

```
if($row['PK_CATEGORIA'] != $categoria){
  //imprime thumb da categria
  $categoria = $row['PK_CATEGORIA'];
}
```

Comment: Não entendi totalmente a parte do controle da impressão. Como exatamente isso deve funcionar? Eu deveria colocar esse if depois do while ou seria a parte?

Comment: e o que colocar no else, por exemplo?

Comment: Fico confuso porque em algunas páginas as thumbs das categorias aparecem repetidas daquela forma (pegando apenas a primeira categoria e duplicando) mas em outras páginas não aparece nenhuma categoria.

Comment: Você coloca esse if na parte em que vc desejar imprimir a thumb. Não precisa de else, pq é imprime ou não imprime as thumbs

Comment: Agora as categorias estão sendo exibidas, mas tem um problema, elas ainda estão se repetindo. Por exemplo, se existem 6 imagens na categoria, ela é repetida 6 vezes, se existem 2 imagens, ela se repete 2 vezes e por ai vai.

Comment: E só estão sendo exibidas as categorias onde a tabela DELETED está como Null, vazias não

Comment: colocou o (TB_CATEGORIA.DELETED IS NULL OR trim(TB_CATEGORIA.DELETED) <> '')

Comment: Agora funcionou! Só falta agora o problema de repetir a categoria. Ao invés de exibir apenas uma thumb, exibe a categoria repetida com cada uma das imagens contidas nela. Por exemplo, a primeira com a imagem 1, a segunda com a imagem 2 e a terceira com a imagem 3, da mesma categoria. Ao invés de pegar apenas uma das imagens e usar como thumb e exibir a categoria uma vez só.

Comment: A ideá da solução está na resposta que te passei...

Comment: Tentei aqui, mas não rolou.

Comment: Cara a lógica é um caminho. Agora é uma questão de entender, e fazer as adaptações necessárias